# How to check login status in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, python, vue.js, authentication, flask

I have an python flask app as backend API, and Vue.js SPA is frontend.

When I click a login button in the frontend, it will **POST** to my flask login api.
I also attach the JWT token on the response cookie.

```py
from flask import Flask,request,jsonify,make_response
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_jwt_extended import (
    JWTManager, jwt_required, create_access_token,
    get_jwt_claims,get_jwt_identity,set_access_cookies
)

@app.route('/login',methods=['POST'])
def login():
    username = request.json.get('username')
    password = request.json.get('password')

    if not(username=='toby5500' and password=='123456'):
        return jsonify({"msg":"404 error"})
    else:
        res = jsonify({"auth":"ok!"})
        #create JWT token 
        access_token = create_access_token(identity=username)
        #attach on response cookie 
        set_access_cookies(res,access_token) # has httponly flag!
        return res
```

Browser's cookie after login:

[image]

**So my question is when i want to go to other pages, what should i do for checking whether this user already login.**

Now my idea is to call backend api to check whether this browser has correct JWT token before routing.

If flask api return error message(not have JWT token), redirect to the login page.

like this

```js
router.beforeEach(async(to,from,next)=>{
    //this api will check jwt token 
    axios.get('/check_jwt').then((res)=>{
        if(res.data.error){
            next({path:'/login'})
        }
        else{
            next()//auth ok
        }
    })
})
```

Is it a correct way to check login?

Comment: Have you checked your user cookies in request.cookies? More information on flask cookies [overiq.com - cookies in flask](https://overiq.com/flask-101/cookies-in-flask/)

Comment: Yes,this my cookie(https://i.imgur.com/c871bhM.png), but i don't know what is the correct way to use this cookie to auth in frontend.

Comment: Usually for my API's I have a `/me` endpoint which returns user information for the logged in user. If it returns a 401 error I know I'm not logged in and redirect to the login page. So yes, basically what you're doing is how I would do it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to re-check token every time you're making request, just check expiration date of your token and handle gracefully 401 error and token refreshing logic. Eg in your before each hook, after pulling token from cookies or vuex:

```
  let isExpired = true
  if (token) {
    isExpired = Date.now() > jwtDecode<{ exp: number }>(token).exp * 1000
  }
  // If no token or expired
  if (!token || isExpired) {
    // ..
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is be reactive here. Instead of checking if the token is valid before making a request, just make your requests like normal. If you ever get an error message back that indicates the JWT is expired (or invalid for other reasons, such as the secret key changing on the backend), then have your frontend then redirect back to the login page.